# Transition an element after reintroducing it into the flow

Tags: html, css, css-transitions

I know that is not possible to `transition` properties like `display`, `position`, `visibility` but how can one add a transition effect (over `opacity` in my case; working either on *show* and *hide*) **AND** being able to put a `display: none` on that element?

There's no need to `transition: display ..`, but just that after it is set to `block` then the transition on `opacity` would start.

I thought I could cheat using `transition: display 0s, opacity .3s` but I can't manage to make it work.

Of course I could use tricks like setting `height: 0; overflow: hidden;` to hide my element but in my case I also **need to remove the element from the flow** (the element is `position: fixed`) **and prevent `TAB`bing on it's descendants** and focusing hidden elements.

Is it using animations the only supported alternative?

No Javascript solutions, please; I believe the presentation should be a concern of CSS.

Comment: Waiting with a setTimeout (yep JS) that the element isn't `display: none` anymore is the only working solution I usually find. What depends on JS is a transition: the kind of Progressive Enhancement I can live with.

Comment: Just wondering if my answer helped.

Comment: Yes it did. I lost some time trying to make it work also when disappearing (transitioning to `display: none`), but looks like @FelipeAls is right on using a JS timeout solution; I couldn't find any pure CSS way to do that. Or did I miss anything?

Comment: I'm aware of that and don't have a solution perhaps it's all you can get with just css.

Comment: Could adapting [CSS3 transitions using visibility and delay](http://www.greywyvern.com/?post=337) of any help? Useful for hoverout but maybe delay could help in your case?

Answer (score 1):

You can probably use CSS animation `@keyframes`. Note, it can add appearing animation, but won't do the disappearing part, as `display:none` will be applied instantly.

```js
function show() {
  var el = document.getElementById("display");
  el.classList.remove("hide");
  el.classList.add("show");
}
```

```css
.hide {
  display: none;
}

.show {
  display: block;
}

.animation {
  animation: fadeIn 2s;
}

@keyframes fadeIn {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<p>
  <input type="text" placeholder="input 1">
</p>

<p id="display" class="animation hide">
  <input type="text" placeholder="input 2">
</p>

<button onclick="show()">show</button>
```